# Is !x equal to true when x is negative?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    
    int x = -1;
                    
    if (!x) {
        printf("Yes\n");
                
    }
}
```

Is `!x` true when `x` is a negative number or it's true when it's only `0`?

Comment: just a convention of the language, 0 is false, anything else is true, so !0 is true and !anything-else is false

Comment: ... so the expression `!x` is equivalent to `x == 0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *any* non-zero `x`, `!x` will be zero. So, for `x == -1`, `!x` is false.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical):

> The logical NOT operator has type int. Its value is ​0​ if expression
> evaluates to a value that compares unequal to zero. Its value is 1 if
> expression evaluates to a value that compares equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Any non-zero value is true even if it is negative value(e.g. -1 is true). So, negation of true is false. In the case of x=-1, if (x) will be evaluated to true, then, !x will be false, and the         printf("Yes\n"); will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the C standard (draft C11, exactly) **6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**, paragraph 5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p5) (bolding mine):

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int. **The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E)**.

So the `!` applied to a negative number is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless one is coding for an ancient dinosaur using non 2's complement with a  negative zero, (-0 is negative and zero), for all integer negative numbers `x`: `!x` --> `(int) 0`.

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to `0`, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.  C17dr § 6.5.3.3 5